# Amazon S3: allow user access to subfolder only on any bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write a policy that will allow a user to read from any bucket (that part works) but only write to a specific subfolder on any bucket.

This is my policy so far (reading works, but it still allows writing to the bucket root):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/test"
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/test/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy the user is still able to write to the root of the bucket, the user should only be able to write the the "test" subfolder on any bucket.

I also tried adding Conditions to the last statement:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*/pdf-test",
        "arn:aws:s3:::*/pdf-test/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "s3:prefix": ["pdf-test/*"] 
        }
    }
}
```

But now the user can't write to anything.

How do I prevent the user from writing to any folder except "test" on any bucket?

Comment: It is more safe to write the full path of the folder you want.